# Fully Qualified arguments break my Executable

Tags: shell, user-permissions

I have an executable that lives in `/var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/bin/`, I can run the executable with the fully qualified name `/var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/bin/myExec`, however, my executable has arguments that live in `/var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/storage/temp`. The arguments cannot be accessed if the using the fully qualified names.

It seems like it's a permissions issue, since the program runs by `apache` user which belongs to `www` group. However, the `www` folder belongs to `root` with group `root`.

If I run

```
/var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/bin/myExec /var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/storage/temp/file1 /var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/storage/temp/file2
```

it fails.
However, running the command from any folder within `vhosts` works fine, for example, running within `app`:

```
/var/www/vhosts/test/htpdocs/app/bin/myExec storage/temp/file1 storage/temp/file2
```

works fine.

It seems like the arguments should work when fully qualified since the subfolders belong to the acting user. I am wondering why this is not so

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Its specific to the executable, so I don't think it's relative but if it helps: `ERROR: Invalid arguments passed to command.`

Comment: That's not a standard shell or C library error. I suspect it's custom logic inside the executable. Can you tell us more about it? Maybe it only wants relative paths. Without knowing more about `myExec` the problem is anyone's guess.

Comment: I only have the executable :/, but I don't think it has anything to do with the logic within the executable. It works fine on one environment with the full path, but doesn't  in my test environment

Comment: @Rodrick : Then you need to get in touch with whoever wrote the executable and clarify what kind of arguments are permitted.